# Use date plus two data sets with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two data set in array being ingested from a csv file that looks like this:

```
['63.72', '64.92', '64.26', '63.62', '64.1', '64.45', '63.69', '62.48', '63.93', '65.47', '65.89', '65.99', '66.34']
```

I want to plot them in a line graph as the y axis, then the x axis be the date/months. Whenever I put it in there, I run into two issues.

1. the numbers above are sorted in order (rather than the way they are in the list above, which corresponds to the date) so the line graph just shoots on an up angle from left to right
2. it seems to make two different graphs, one above the other, and it doesn't show the relationships between the two data sets.

Here's the code:

```
date_array = np.array(date_list)
chrome_array = np.array(chrome_list)
safari_array = np.array(safari_list)

plt.title("Web Browser Market Share")
plt.xlabel("Date Range by Month")
plt.ylabel("Percentage of Market Share")
plt.ylim(0, 20)
plt.plot_date(date_array, safari_array, data=df, color='blue',
              markersize=15, linewidth=4, markerfacecolor='white',
              markeredgewidth=2, label='Chrome Browser')
plt.plot(date_array, chrome_array, data=df, color='grey',
         markersize=15, linewidth=4, markerfacecolor='white',
         markeredgewidth=2, label='Safari Browser')
  
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here's what I see:
[image]

Comment: You probably need to convert your values from string to numeric. Otherwise, your y-axis will be interpreted as text labels instead of numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I did this with the following code:     [[float(x) for x in s.split(',')] for s in chrome_list]
    [[float(x) for x in s.split(',')] for s in safari_list]

Comment: The internal notation that converts to float form is written like this. `chrome_list = [float(s) for s in chrome_list]`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue thanks to r-beginners and JohanC. They cued me in to the data type being incorrect, and I solved it (one way of many) with the following code, which is right before the first line of code above:

```
    chrome_float = []
    for item in chrome_list:
        chrome_float.append(float(item))

    safari_float = []
    for item in safari_list:
        safari_float.append(float(item))
```